# Window top just works sometimes. What makes it stop working?

Tags: javascript, html, frames

Im working with an old webpage using frames. 
At one place Im calling a webpage with this line in javascript:
parent.parent.fr_hidden.location = "logg_sortering_hidden.html?what=kund&kundid=" + sendString;

In the logg_sortering_hidden.html I then have the following javascript line to refer to select called f_proodukt:
window.top[3].fr_top.contentDocument.formen.f_produkt.innerHTML = "";

This works great most of the time, but not always. The thing is, that I cannot figure out why it doesnt always work. Its the window.top[3] that suddenly fails.
It works like 95% of the time, and when it works I just cant get it to not work, so I cannot even fault seek as why this is.

If anyone could help me out on when window.top stops working this would be great help. Its the same call everytime but still not the same result.
Please help.

```
/* Körs varje gång vi byter kunder i riktiga menyn*/
    function kund_change()
    {
        /* Make sure that jquery works so that this code works*/    
        var valuesKund = $('#f_kund').val();
        var sendString = "";
        var i;

        /* Lägger till valda kunder som children till input elementet kund_selected, dessa används då vi postar formen så att vi velt vad vi valt.*/
        document.getElementById("kund_selected").innerHTML = "";
        for(i = 0 ; i < valuesKund.length; i++){            
            var kundChild = document.createElement("input");
            kundChild.setAttribute("type", "hidden");           
            kundChild.setAttribute("name", "KundChild" + String(i));
            //kundChild.innerHTML = valuesKund[i];
            kundChild.setAttribute("value", valuesKund[i]);
            document.getElementById("kund_selected").appendChild(kundChild);

            sendString = sendString  + valuesKund[i] + "ZZZ"; 
        }

        //document.getElementById("kund_selected").value = sendString;      

        var self = this;
        parent.parent.fr_hidden.location = "logg_sortering_hidden.html?what=kund&kundid=" + sendString;



    }
```

Comment: Could you post a code snippet?

Comment: Well, thos were the relevant lines I think, but heres the javascript function in logg_sortering.html :